# php - How to generate MySQL INSERT statements to populate a table with multiple rows from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, while-loop

I have read in a CSV file containing recipe data with over 4000 rows. At index 7 is the category such as 'breakfast', 'vegan' etc. I am going to make a many to many table in MySQL between the recipes and their categories, but first I am generating `INSERT` statements for a category table. I needed to get rid of duplicate values (of which there are many) and have done this successfully using `array_unique()`.

I'm generating insert statements instead of putting data directly into my database because I'm still unsure of what I'm doing.

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
 
include("connection.php");
 
 
$file = "recipes.csv";
$categories = array();
 
if (file_exists($file)) {
 
    $filepath = fopen($file, "r");

    while( ($line = fgetcsv($filepath)) !== FALSE ){

        $categories[] = $line[7];


        $categories = array_unique($categories);
        $catstr = implode(" , ",$categories);

        echo "INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('".$catstr."')";
        
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

I wasn't sure about using the implode function, perhaps I am using it wrong.

Here is the output:

```
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat , Sauces')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat , Sauces , Low Protein')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat , Sauces , Low Protein , < 15 Mins')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat , Sauces , Low Protein , < 15 Mins')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat , Sauces , Low Protein , < 15 Mins')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat , Sauces , Low Protein , < 15 Mins , Cheesecake')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European , Dessert , < 30 Mins , Steak , Chicken Breast , Lunch/Snacks , Breakfast , Candy , Ice Cream , Chicken , Gelatin , Meat , Sauces , Low Protein , < 15 Mins , Cheesecake')
```

.... and so on.

My code is obviously outputting something for every original index value as well as outputting all the previous category values with every iteration.

What I need it to do:

```
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('European')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('Dessert')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('< 30 Mins')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('Steak')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('Chicken Breast')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('Lunch/Snacks')
INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('Breakfast')

etc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why  not share an extract from the file (e.g. the first 5 lines, the middle 5 lines, and the last 5 lines)

Answer (score 1):

It is not very complex just add last element of each line. because every time category is unique and last element is defined as new category for each row

```
<?php
 
// include("connection.php");
 
 
$file = "recipes.csv";
$categories = array();
 
if (file_exists($file)) {
 
    $filepath = fopen($file, "r");

    while( ($line = fgetcsv($filepath)) !== FALSE ){

        $cat =end($line);
        echo "INSERT INTO category (categoryname) VALUES ('". $cat."')";
        
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```php
<?php
$db = new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$file = "recipes.csv";

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO category SET categoryname = ?");
    $filepath = fopen($file, "r");

    while(($line = fgetcsv($filepath)) !== false) {
        $categories[] = $line[7];
    }
    $categories = array_unique($categories);
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $stmt->execute([$cat]);
    }
}
```

Loop through the CSV first so you can get your unique values, and then use a prepared statement to insert each one in turn. This assumes you're using PDO, and will obviously need some error checking code added.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am using MySQLi

Comment: You should not be. If you want to continue, there's plenty of material out there on how to do prepared statements with it.